# AngularJS Boilerplate works on Codepen but on on JSFiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I was trying to write a simple Angular app, when I came upon a problem. My perfectly simple and short boilerplate code runs entirely fine in a Codepen, but it fails to work in a JSFiddle. The snippet I created below works fine as well, but I cannot figure out why it does not work in JSFiddle. Could anyone point out what the problem is?

**Codepen link:** http://codepen.io/chalarangelo/pen/YWdvBV

**JSFiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/chalarangelo/1d12hm5f/1/

**Code snippet:**

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myController', [
   '$scope',
   function($scope) {
     $scope.demoText = 'AngularJS: This is some demo text!';
   }
 ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p>
      {{ demoText }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should click the `JAVASCRIPT` button and select an Angular version under the `FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS` dropdown, instead of including it as an external resource.

[image: Javascript options in JSFiddle]

To fix your problem, you must select the `LOAD TYPE` as `No wrap - in <head>`.

Comment: Selecting Angular from the menu did not solve the problem as I have loaded the script already and tried this itself. However, using `No wrap - in <head>` under `LOAD TYPE` fixes the problem for me. Thank you!